# Allowlist wallet based or discord base

Tags: rust, nft, python

How to implement the Allowlist Wallet base or discord base? i have an a issue on wallet based on CMV2 cause they gonna mint unli using the bot.

Comment: please elaborate what you would like to implement, what you've built so far, where you're stuck. provide source samples, etc.

Comment: Check the Crossmint tools for creating Allowlist using Discord.

Answer (score 1):

Candy machine out of the box doesn't support wallet-based whitelists. Obviously it doesn't support Discord authentication based whitelists either.

You could set up a mint site that sends the user's connected wallet to your server, which holds the list of whitelisted wallets. If the user's wallet is in the list, the server renders a page with the mint button. Same logic can be applied with Discord authentication. However this isn't totally secure, because this ONLY determines which UI the user sees. It will block the majority of non-whitelisted users, but people would still be able to bypass your UI and mint directly off of your candy machine.

The one fool-proof way to do this, is to use a custom solana program that takes the wallet/discordID as an input, and does the mint internally if it's whitelisted.

Another alternative method is to execute the mint on a back-end server to the user's wallet, but then you wont be using candymachine.